# Using "git pull" command without "--rebase" tag for merging branches

Tags: git, merge

There are many similar questions to this one, but I still can't get it.

In our team, we use "git pull" to merge branches, instead of "git fetch" + "git merge". When I've tried to search on web, if it is a correct flow - there were various topics like "Ok, you can use git pull --rebase instead, but it is risky". I can understand this - but in our team we do not use rebase.

For example, when we need to merge branch1 and branch2 and then send it to devbranch we simply do it like:

1. git pull origin branch1 (from devbranch)
2. git pull origin branch2 (from devbranch) *resolve conflicts if there are any
3. *check locally if everything works fine*
4. git push origin devbranch
5. *pull latest (merged) code from devbranch using branch1 and branch2*

We have no issues by now using this workflow, but I am just wondering - if this flow is fine and does it have any issues?

Comment: You're not using `git pull` *instead of* `git fetch && git merge`, you're using `git pull` *to run* `git fetch && git merge`. That's what `git pull` does: it runs `git fetch` followed by a second Git command. The second command is `git merge` by default.

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you. So doing things in this way doesn't cause any issues, right? That's what I want to confirm..

Comment: I just wondering - if this flow is fine, what are the cases when using fetch and merge commands separately is necessary?

Comment: Whilst I don't prefer `git pull --rebase` it certainly isn't risky.

Comment: It's never *necessary* to use separate commands. I mostly prefer doing so, however, because I tend to want to inspect the commits that `git fetch` fetched before I decide what, if anything, I want to do with their vs my commits. When you use `git pull` you must make this decision blindly, without seeing what will be fetched. If you know you always want to use `git merge` (or always `git rebase`), it becomes possible to make the decision blindly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought of adding this as a comment, but then it took more words than I intended so I post it as an answer instead.

> we use "git pull" to merge branches, instead of "git fetch" + "git
>   merge".

Well actually when you run git pull, it runs fetch and merge / rebase commands in background, depending on the parameters you use..

> In its default mode, git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by
>   git merge FETCH_HEAD.
>
> More precisely, git pull runs git fetch with the given parameters and
>   calls git merge to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current
>   branch. With --rebase, it runs git rebase instead of git merge.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

===============================================================

> "Ok, you can use git pull --rebase instead, but it is risky". I can
>   understand this..

I think this is a bit misleading. Rebase is not risky as long as you don't rewrite the history of public branches. ( it would cause a lot of confusions ).

But say for an example, if you are working on a feature branch, and you want to stay up to date with your remote dev branch, then you can rebase to keep your branch's history up to date, and clean at the same time. One advantage of using rebase regularly is that you will solve a lot of merge conflicts at early stages and also your commit history will be linear (since you can avoid all the unwanted merge commits).

Hope it helps :) Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Your flow is fine and works pretty well when all people using the repository have a basic understanding of the defined `git` flow, Indeed your `develop` and probably `master` branch would keep a clean history by just being fast forwarding when merging between them.

Now the `git pull --rebase` I would say is like a lifesaver to `git` newcomers, mainly because after cloning, they have no idea about "branches" and start editing directly into the `master` branch instead of creating their own branch, etc, therefore when they want to update their local repository `git pull` but would like to keep their changes without creating a new branch, the `--rebase` option becomes handy.